# reshape2: dcast tall into wide without aggregating

Tags: r, reshape2

Consider

```
ext <- data.frame(cond = rep(c('a', 'b'), each = 2), dat = runif(4) )
```

I want

```
exw <- unstack(ext, dat ~ cond)
```

But I would like to do it with `dcast()` in `reshape2` (for pedagogical purposes). Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

You have to tell `dcast` that there is an identifying row id:

For example:

```
dcast(ext, 1:2~cond)
  1:2         a         b
1   1 0.5706567 0.4360110
2   2 0.0305229 0.7032459
```

And, more generally:

```
ext$id <- sequence(rle(as.character(ext$cond))$lengths)
dcast(ext, id~cond, value.var="dat")

  id         a         b
1  1 0.5706567 0.4360110
2  2 0.0305229 0.7032459
```